# How do I sort an ArrayList include Date and String?

Tags: java

I want to sort my ArrayList by Date.
My ArrayList as:

```
10 June - name
15 April - name
23 July - name
03 March - name
```

It has day, month and string name. How do I sort by Date?

Thanks

Comment: is your array list ArrayList<String>? is "10 June - name" one object? or is it splitted to 2/3/? objects?

Comment: yes "10 June -name" one object.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by @The Elite Gentleman, you should use a custom comparator. Here's a complete example:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList("10 June - name", 
                              "15 April - name", 
                              "23 July - name", 
                              "03 March - name"));

        // Print list before sorting.
        System.out.println(list);

        // Sort list according to date.
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                try {
                    Date d1 = df.parse(s1.split("-")[0].trim());
                    Date d2 = df.parse(s2.split("-")[0].trim());
                    return d1.compareTo(d2);
                } catch (ParseException pe) {
                    System.out.println("erro: " + pe);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });

        // Print list after sorting
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[10 June - name, 15 April - name, 23 July - name, 03 March - name]
[03 March - name, 15 April - name, 10 June - name, 23 July - name]
```

(**A better idea** may however be encapsulate the date/name pairs into a separate class. This would avoid the need to parse the string each time it needs to be used for these type of purposes.)

Comment: Hah, you think? I try to never solve homework assignments at SO, so I hope this wasn't homework :P

Comment: No problem. You're welcome. Be sure to upvote all answers that you found helpful and accept (by clicking on the checkmark) the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own date [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and pass sort it using [`Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T> c);`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method.

Comment: +1, This is the way to go. See my answer for a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Comment: Given his data is represented as strings, I can't see how `Comparable` would help him here.

Answer (score 0):

In the Collections class there is a static method called [sort(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) where you can pass a list and a comparator.

Create a comparator that compares the values from the list and return the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

Here you an example:

```
List<Date> dates=new ArrayList<Date>();
dates.add(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
dates.add(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+231892738));
dates.add(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-742367634));
for(Date d:dates)
    System.out.println(d);
Collections.sort(dates);
for(Date d:dates)
    System.out.println(d);
```

Or you can use custom comparator

```
Collections.sort(dates,customComparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Collections.sort` method for your case:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<String>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
          // perform the comparison here and returns a negative integer,
          // zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than,
          // equal to, or greater than the second 
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function which turns that date string into an int? 
i.e.

```
str2int("name 10 June") => 610
str2int("name 15 Jan")  => 115

int str2int(String s){
    String[] elms = s.split("\\s+");
    // ignore first argument which is name
    int day = Integer.parseInt(elms[1]);
    int month = month2int(elms[2]);
    return day + month;
}

// month2int("Jan") => 100
// month2int("Feb") => 200
// .
// .
// month2int("Dec") => 1200

// you get the idea :-)
```

use a comparator which compares those Strings like that..